# Javascript : format string and avoid multiple replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string :

```
var str='
                <span class="productName">Basa fillets</span><br>
                Brand: 
                <span class="brandName">COMPLIMENTS</span><br>
                400 <abbr title="Gram" lang="en">gr</abbr>
            '
```

I need to get the '400' (could be a word,or even a sentence). 
What I have so far is :

```
d = str.replace(/<br>/g,'').replace(/<.*<\/.*>/g,'').replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/ */g,'').replace(/brand:/i,'');
```

It works but... well, I'm sure I can do better. i have plenty of similar queued replace in my code, and I'd like to know how to improve that so i'm more looking for a general answer than a particular solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Your string isn't valid you either need to escape the `"` symbol with `\"` or use `'` inside the main string.  changing it to `var str="<span class='productName'>Basa fillets</span><br>Brand: <span class='brandName'>COMPLIMENTS</span><br>400 <abbr title='Gram' lang='en'>gr</abbr>";`

Comment: or change the "" around it with '. Edited, was obviously a typo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using string tools/regex on this, you can use DOM methods on it (it *is* HTML).

First you make a "fake" div and add the HTML to it.

```
var str="\
                <span class=\"productName\">Basa fillets</span><br>\
                Brand: \
                <span class=\"brandName\">COMPLIMENTS</span><br>\
                400 <abbr title=\"Gram\" lang=\"en\">gr</abbr>\
            ";

var fakeDiv = document.createElement('div');
fakeDiv.innerHTML = str;
```

Then just use normal DOM traversal methods to get the node you need.  There are many ways to get to the element, depending on your HTML.

```
var brandName = fakeDiv.getElementsByClassName('brandName');

var textNode = brandName[0].nextSibling.nextSibling;

console.log(textNode.nodeValue.trim());
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aqpgV/

Or, you can start from the `<abbr>` element and work backwards.

```
var gram = fakeDiv.getElementsByTagName('abbr');

var textNode = gram[0].previousSibling;

console.log(textNode.nodeValue.trim());
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aqpgV/1/

However you traverse it is up to you :-)

Comment: Great answer, I wouldn't have thought of the fakeDiv! thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D  Yeah, you don't actually need elements to actually be in the DOM to be able to use them ;-)

Comment: If you need to support IE8, you won't have `getElementsByClassName`, but you could use `fakeDiv.querySelector('.brandName');` since there is only one element with class "brandName".

Comment: @TomPietrosanti: Thanks.  I forgot `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
class="brandName">[^<]+</span><br>[^\w]+([^<]+) <abbr title=
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZR__Z9d2MAa_t8Np)

***Notes:** Group 1 will contain the item you want.*

Comment: sexy! but my teammates will pull their hair with that one :-D thanks!

Comment: @xShirase completely understandable, I honestly think using html's native concepts and manipulation for getting items is more appropriate for this.  Just wanted to give you a quick example of some RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use regex, you could do something like this.

```
    var str="\
            <span class=\"productName\">Basa fillets</span><br>\
            Brand: \
            <span class=\"brandName\">COMPLIMENTS</span><br>\
            400 <abbr title=\"Gram\" lang=\"en\">gr</abbr>\
        ";

    var myRegexp = /COMPLIMENTS<\/span><br>\W(.*?) <abbr /g;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(str);
    alert(match[1]);
```